pubic key not avaliable error
sudo apt-get update when i run this i got this error.
i got this error:
Err:3 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0686B78420038257

when i tried this:
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 6494C6D6997C215E
i got this error:
      Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.PomW8URa3F/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 6494C6D6997C215E
gpg: key 7721F63BD38B4796: 2 duplicate signatures removed
gpg: key 7721F63BD38B4796: "Google Inc. (Linux Packages Signing Authority) <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1

please solve this

You've not provided your Ubuntu release, so our ability to help is somewhat limited.  Your attempt to add another key also differs to the key that was reported as missing.
